# What is the view: mean?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I've upgraded my MVC project and VS2008 to MVC2 and VS2010. When returning ActionResult for controller actions I notice the intellisense gives `view:` option. What is this about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is optional arguments. Optional arguments simply let’s you omit argument values and named arguments let’s you enter them in any order you’d like.

```
public int Test(int a, int b = 1, int c = 2, int d = 3) {
    return a + b + c + d;
}

public string Hello(string name = "World") {
    return "Hello, " + name + "!";
}

public void Main() {
    Test(0);            //Test(0,1,2,3)

    Test(0, c: 5);      //Test(0,1,5,3)

    Test(d: 5, a: 0);   //Test(0,1,2,5)

    Hello();            //Hello("World");
}
```